# How can i create a Pip for exoPlayer in Android koltin

Tags: android, kotlin, picture-in-picture

I want to create a picture in picture in android kotlin with navigation componenet
but i want that show in app and dont close the app
how can i do that
Does anyone have an example of it?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the official documentation.

**By default, the system does not automatically support PiP for apps. If you want to support PiP in your app, register your video activity in your manifest by setting android:supportsPictureInPicture to true. Also, specify that your activity handles layout configuration changes so that your activity doesn't relaunch when layout changes occur during PiP mode transitions.**

```
<activity android:name="VideoActivity"
android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
android:configChanges=
    "screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
```

Read rest steps from documentation here: [Pip support](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture#:%7E:text=PiP%20is%20a%20special%20type,content%20on%20the%20main%20screen.)